# Dynamically update values form database against selected index in Combobox

Tags: java, eclipse, combobox, jframe

Scenario is, There is combobox and 2 textfields. Combobox items (model) are fetched from database and update Combobox dynamically. **I have done it.**

Now i need to do that when user select any item(model) from Combobox then its name and price should be updated in textfields.

How to do it ?

//This code only have one textfield one i will make after.

```
    public class Purchases extends JFrame {
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;
    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
     String model, name;


    /**
         * Launch the application.
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Purchases frame = new Purchases();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });     
        }

        /**
         * Create the frame.
         */

        public Purchases() {
            try {
        String host;
        host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sfs_electronics";// [root on Default schema]";
        String uName = "root";
        String uPass= "";


Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( host, uName, uPass );
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement( );
    String SQL = "SELECT * FROM purchases";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( SQL );
    while(rs.next())
         {
         model= rs.getString("Model");
         name= rs.getString("Name");
         comboBox.addItem(model);    // Adding Items in ComboBox
        System.out.println(model);
         }
       }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }


            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setBounds(100, 100, 501, 420);
            contentPane = new JPanel();
            contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            setContentPane(contentPane);
            contentPane.setLayout(null);


        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(10, 10, 465, 146);
        contentPane.add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                int n=comboBox.getSelectedIndex();
                System.out.println(n);
                System.out.println(comboBox.getSelectedItem());
                textField.setText(?????);  //Here What i need to code that selected models name should be place here. 
            }
        });

        comboBox.setBounds(109, 11, 86, 20);
        panel.add(comboBox);        
        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(109, 47, 86, 20);
        panel.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);                   
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code will be placed in `comboBox.addActionListener`.

```
//Connect database 
String s = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
String SQL = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `Model` = '" + s + "'"; 
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( SQL );
while(rs.next())
{
    requiredtextfield.setText(rs.getString("ColumnNAme_of_database"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Please always describe your answer. Also keep in minde to use prepared statements to avoid sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce a class Purchase with all necessary fields from DB you are going to use

```
public class Purchase {
  int id;
  String name;
  String model;
...
  public String toString() {
      return model;
  }
}
```

On retrieving data from DB create Purchase instances filling the fields from your result set. Place the purchase items in the combobox. TO provide correct showing you can either add your renderer which shows model field of the item (more complicated) or just override toString() method of Purchase class to return model field.

When somethinf is selected in the combobox the selected item is particular purchase instance and you can use the name field to reflect in the text field.

Comment: I did not get too much what you said. but i try to do. Thanks

Comment: Purchase class to return model field. Can i get little code of it ?